# Modifying global dictionary in python within a function

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def modify_dict():

    d['two'] = 2

d = {'one':1}

modify_dict()

print d
```

I get

```
$ ./globaltest.py 
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

I was hoping to see only `{'one':1}`  since d is not declared global within the function. Why did d get both key-value pairs ?

Comment: Because `d` is mutable and the operation you performed on `d` inside dictionary is not be considered as an assignment operation by functions.
For example with lists(mutable object) `+=` operator will raise error in function body, but .append and .extend and assignment by index will work fine.

Comment: To expand - when you assign (`x = y`) to a variable inside a function, python implicitly decides you're referring to a local. The syntax `d[k] = x` resolves to a `__setitem__` call - so while it looks syntactically like assignment, it is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the global keyword not required in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081308/why-is-the-global-keyword-not-required-in-this-case)

Answer (score 3):

Python search for variables is based on the `LEGB` rule:

```
Local, Enclosing functions, Global, Built-in
```

When you call your function it tries to find a variable named d, and will find in global scope since you   created d before calling the function. And since d is mutable, it will get updated.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) of python. Dictionaries and lists are mutable objects, which is why globally defined dictionaries for example do not need to be declared `global`. Their contents may be changed at any time.

To understand mutability, think of the strings in python. They are an *immutable* object. You can for example replace the contents of a given string but in doing so the interpreter creates a new string object, and thus gives this string object a new identity (and thus a memory address).

```
>>> s = "foo"
>>> id(s)
140202745404072
>>> s = "bar"
>>> id(s)
140202745404112
```

I've answered [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333523/inconsistent-variable-scope-in-python/23333551#23333551) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386816/global-varialbes-in-python/23386884#23386884) questions before, so take a look if you can find more information from them.

Answer (score 2):

In a quick workaround is copy dictionary in local scope of the function.

```
import copy

d = {'one':1}

def modify_dict():
    local_d = copy.deepcopy(d)
    local_d['two'] = 2
    print local_d

modify_dict()
print d
```

you will see output following :

```
>>>{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
>>>{'one': 1}
```