# Python global vs dict

Tags: python, global-variables

Why does the following variable not pass to the closure:

```
def something():
    UPDATED = 0
    def _inner():
        UPDATED += 1
```

But this one does:

```
def something():
    UPDATED = {0:0}
    def _inner():
        UPDATED[0] += 1
```

I find myself using the latter approach as a sort of hack to get around referencing a global var, but why does that one work and the first doesn't?

Comment: `nonlocal` (which Python version is this?)

Comment: `Python 3.6.3`.

Comment: You know... edit the question and add the language tag.

Comment: @user202729 ok but that tagged duplicate mentions nothing about dicts.

Comment: there's one for `global` [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25905300) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14081308)  [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6329499) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31435603)  [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23436385)  but I can't find any for `nonlocal`...